# Is there any static vector of types?

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any static (compiler-time) vector of types? For example, I can get a type by a given constant integer index, like the following

```
Vector<int, float>::Type<0> is int

Vector<int, float>::Type<1> is float
```

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/generic-programmingtypelists-and-applica/184403813

Comment: What compiler? Do you have one that supports all the C++11 goodness (variadic templates, I'm looking at you)? (And have a look at [`std::tuple_element`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple_element/).)

Comment: I think std::tuple works. Thank you!

Comment: `std::tuple` holds an instance of each type. If you only need the types, search for "type lists". There is a `TypeList` in the [Loki library](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/). There may well be C++11 versions out there.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to manipulate a vector of types at compile time, you can use `boost::mpl::vector` from the Boost.MPL library. But beware, your head might explode.

```
using namespace boost::mpl;

typedef at_c<vector<int, float>, 0>::type t1; // int
typedef at_c<vector<int, float>, 1>::type t2; // float
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/vector.html

Answer (score 3):

Typelist in [loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/) does exactly that. Loki is a library designed and developed by Andrei Alexandrescu. The whole library is template based. In particular, typelist (one of the basic components of the library) gives you plenty of compile-time algorithms which allow you to perform pretty much every operation you want to perform on a list (e.g. access by index, find, remove duplicates, ...). Typelist per se is extremely simple:

```
template <class T, class U> 
struct Typelist 
{ 
 typedef T Head; 
 typedef U Tail; 

}; 
namespace TL 
{ 
 ...typelist algorithms ... 
}
```

its power comes from the algorithms it provides. Such algorithms are all executed at compile-time.

The TypleList facilities are described in great detail in the book Modern C++ (Alexandrescu)

In particular, indexed access is implemented as:

```
template <class Head, class Tail> 
struct TypeAt<Typelist<Head, Tail>, 0> 
{ 
 typedef Head Result;
}; 
template <class Head, class Tail, unsigned int i> 
struct TypeAt<Typelist<Head, Tail>, i> 
{ 
 typedef typename TypeAt<Tail, i - 1>::Result Result; 
};
```

so that

```
TypeAt<MyList, 5>::Result a(...);
```

creates an object named "a" of the 6th type in MyList.

Comment: Could you expand on your answer? Not all readers may know what you mean by Loki.

Answer (score 3):

`std::tuple` already provides this functionality.

```
std::tuple_element<1, std::tuple<int, float>>::type // float
std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<int, float>>::type // int
```

Comment: The problem with tuple is that it is not meant to be a mere collection of types, so that if you want to hold a tuple, you need to construct all the elements, which might not be feasible (besides, it might also become a memory problem, depending on the types your are enumerating).

Comment: @Stefano: You don't need to construct a tuple to use it in this fashion. That's a completely separate functionality.